# Autenticação API bearer Cliente

Tags: c#, api, owin

Tenho uma **API** que retornar token **bearer**, normal, conforme imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A dúvida é o seguinte, tem uma aplicação **MVC** que consome essa API, e quero colocar **[Authorize]** nas classes dessa aplicação MVC e que faça autenticação com o token da **API**, é possível? se sim, como devo fazer?

```
private async Task<List<string>> GetToken(string UserName, string password)
    {            
        List<string> lstResult = new List<string>();
        string[] resultResponse = new string[2];

        var parametros = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        LoginModel param = new LoginModel { UserName = UserName, Password = password};

        IRestResponse restResponse = await APIIdentity.ResponseAPIPostToken_RestSharp("/token", param);

        var token = JToken.Parse(restResponse.Content);
        var obj = JObject.Parse((string)token.ToString());

        int statusCode = (int)restResponse.StatusCode;

        if ((int)statusCode > 200)
        {
            resultResponse[0] = Convert.ToString((int)statusCode);
            resultResponse[1] = obj["error_description"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            resultResponse[0] = Convert.ToString((int)statusCode);
            resultResponse[1] = obj["access_token"].ToString();
        }

        lstResult.AddRange(resultResponse);

        return lstResult;
    }

 public static async Task<IRestResponse> ResponseAPIPostToken_RestSharp(string URIResource, LoginModel objParam)
    {
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient(string.Format("{0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIUrl"]));
        RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("/token", Method.POST);

        string encodedBody = string.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}", objParam.UserName, objParam.Password);
        restRequest.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", encodedBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        restRequest.AddParameter("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", ParameterType.HttpHeader);

        return await restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(restRequest);
    }
```